# How to create wordpress dashboard sub menu pages dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to create sub menu pages depending on the options? In my plugin option page I got an input field for titles (of the submenu pages). These titles are separated by commas. I tried following in my plugin script:

```
function my_menu() {
    global $page_hook_suffix;
    $page_hook_suffix = add_menu_page(...); //adding main menu
    $titles=get_option('my_option_name');
    $titles=explode(",",$titles);
    if(!empty(get_option('my_option_name'))){
        foreach($titles as $title){     
            $slug = str_replace(' ', '_', $title);
            add_submenu_page("main_menu_name", "$title", "$title", 'manage_options', "$slug", "$slug");
        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_menu' );
```

That works so far. But now I need to display content on that sub menu pages. But is it even possible to create (content) functions dynamically? I don't know how to use a function name as variable.

I tried this:

```
if(!empty(get_option('my_option_name'))){
    foreach($titles as $title){     
        $slug = str_replace(' ', '_', $title) . "()";
        function $slug {
            echo "hi!";
        }
    }   
}
```

Looks stupid and doesn't work of course. Following error occurs:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$slug' (T_VARIABLE)

Is it even possible? If yes, how to use variables as function names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval() was the solution:

```
if(!empty(get_option('my_option_name'))){
    $titles=get_option('my_option_name');
    $titles=explode(",",$titles);
    foreach($titles as $title){     
        $slug = str_replace(' ', '_', $title);            
        eval(' function '.$slug.'() {
            echo '.$title.';
            }'
        );            
    }   
}
```